Имеется двумерный массив данных x и y, адаптировать значения y под новые значения x
Существует величина Fi(l), где Fi есть величина спектральной плотности потока излучения Солнца на орбите Земли (Вт/м2/нм) и l - длина волны УФ излучения (нм), эти данные представлены в виде таблицы Excel. Вопрос: каким способом можно подобрать значения Fi(l) для новых значений l, пробовал линейной и сплайн интерполяциями - не подходит, возможно, нужно строить математическую модель и уже на её основе что-то вычислять, вдруг кто-то сталкивался с подобным.
Перечень данных прикладываю:
 l_Fi       Fi        new_l
_____    ________    ______

  0.5    2.28e-06      0.3
  0.5    2.28e-06     0.44
  0.5    2.28e-06      0.8
  1.5    0.000122      1.8
  2.5    1.51e-05      2.3
  3.5    2.52e-05      3.1
  4.5    3.71e-05      4.4
  4.5    3.71e-05        5
  6.5    4.37e-05     6.15
  9.5    1.65e-05       10
 14.5    2.14e-05       15
 19.5    0.000204       20
 24.5    4.76e-05       25
30.05    0.000625       30
 34.5    6.94e-05       35
 39.5    5.83e-06       40
 44.5    4.39e-06       45
 49.5    3.97e-05       50
 54.5    4.84e-06       55
 59.5    7.78e-06       60
 64.5    2.44e-06       65
 69.5    4.45e-06       70
 74.5    6.16e-06       75
 79.5    1.43e-05       80
 84.5    3.06e-05       85
 89.5    5.98e-05       90
 94.5     1.2e-05       95
 99.5    2.27e-05      100


Это одномерная зависимость.  возможно, нужно строить математическую модель - без сомнений. Спектр излучения абсолютно чёрного тела не подходит?

Забавно... Получается ярко выраженный максимум для 1,5 нм. При том что у Солнца максимум приходится где-то на 500 нм, если не ошибаюсь... Т.е. это не спектр абсолютно черного тела, так что это никак не гладкая кривая, и угадать, что там будет, мягко говоря, сложновато. В любом случае надо на этом хвостике работать в лучшем случае с логарифмами. "На орбите" - это в космосе или на поверхности Земли? Если на Земле - то это явно какие-то поглощения атмосферой, если в космосе - скорее какие-то пики излучения для каких-то линий. Вобщем, просто эта задача точно не решается.

Точно, спектр там веселый - сплошные горбовпадины. Не думаю, что вы их по трем точкам сможете построить. Это только первокурсники физфака на лабах ничтоже сумняшеся прямую по двум точкам строят :)

Нда, там же излучение/поглощение на определённых частотах происходит, как вы из одной части спектра другую вычислять собираетесь? Это невозможно. )  Ну то есть можно что-то усреднённое нарисовать, но не более того, реальный спектр так не построить. А вообще нужно строить график по всем данным и смотреть глазами, как он выглядит, прежде чем пытаться формулы какие-то применять.

@MBo, пробую строить график по формуле Планка в отрезке тех же длин волн, графики совсем не совпадают, возможно, делаю что-то не то, но условно беру температуру Солнца в 5771 К.

@Harry 3 точки я привёл в пример, всего я отсортировал 28. Вообще задача заключается в расчёте вероятности фотоионизации молекулы воды в околоземном космическом пространстве. Одна из подзадача заключается в "подгонке" значений спектральной плотности под другие величины длин волн.

А можете в вопрос все данные добавить? 3 точки - это реально ни о чём вообще.

@CrazyElf откорректировал  текст вопроса.

А new_l колонка ведь сама по себе, она же не связана со значениями в двух других колонках? И ещё как вы поняли, что сплайны вам не подходят? Зависимость там не линейная, но сплайны или полиномы довольно большой степени вроде должны подойти.

Верно, колонка new_l сама по себе. Я пробовал а матлабе сплайнами и полиномом 3й степени, результут не совсем подходил, было что-то на подобие 0.0ХХХ и т.п то есть числа более низких порядков.

Ну такое. Если бы вам просто в промежуточных точках нужно было, то scipy.interpolate.interp1d вполне справляется. А если прямо формулу нужно, то я попробовал полиномы Чебышева и да, что-то даже 20-й степени по большому счёту ерунда получается, зубцы эти он не ловит нормально. Ну, повторюсь, спектр и не должен полиномами описываться, это же пики или низы наоборот на конкретных спектральных линиях, поэтому вообще не очень понятно, что же вы пытаетесь сделать, если вдуматься. Это не для полиномов задача вообще.

@CrazyElf как раз таки в промежуточных точках значения и нужны, не получается как можно это более менее адекватно обработать, видимо собственного представления не хватает...В любом случае спасибо, буду пробовать как-то сплайнами подгонять

Но ведь 0.3 и 100 - это не промежуточные точки, это за границами. Я потом как время буду покажу как interp1d пользоваться. Там ничего сложного.

@CrazyElf мне нужно интерполировать в отрезке от 0.3 до 100, и в начале графика есть загвоздка там, где значение при 0.5 нм подгоняю под 0.3 и 0.44, получаются отрицательные числа, интерполирую сплайн-интерполяцией.

@СергейГалкин Спасибо результат, намного лучше. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, пожалуйста, как лучше обработать первые 3 пары, там где дублируются длины волн.

Если по какой-то причине трудно вручную удалить, то можно так:
l_Fi=unique(l_Fi,'stable'); Fi=unique(Fi,'stable');

Если вам надо конкретно значения в новых точках получить, то в Матлабе команда interp1 прекрасно с этим справляется.
Сначала уберите повторяющиеся значения в l_Fi и Fi
Потом наберите код
new_Fi=interp1(l_Fi,Fi,new_l,'pchip','extrap');
new_Fi=new_Fi.*(new_Fi>0);

